# Property 'csrf_token' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage

this is a simple question.

I'm trying to do a login with angular 5 and Drupal 8 for the backend. The connection works fine, and I can send the JSON to the Drupal site, and it returns me a CSRF token.

Now I want to add it to my localstorage.

This is the login function in my login.service.ts

```
login (user: User): Observable<User> {
      const url = `${this.mainUrl}user/login?_format=json`;  
    const loginReturn = this.http.post(url, user, httpHaljson);   
    console.log (loginReturn);    

    return loginReturn 
    .map(user => 
      {
     // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      return user;           
     })   
    .pipe( 
        tap((user: User) => this.log(`Token `+  JSON.stringify(user.csrf_token))),
        catchError(this.handleError<User>('login'))
      );
}
```

If I try to do something like this:

```
.map(user => 
              {
             // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
              localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
              console.log ('object' + JSON.stringify(user));
              console.log ('CSRF TOKEN' + JSON.stringify(user.csrf_token));
              return user;           
             })
```

It shows me the console log of my csrf token, perfectly fine, but I got this error on the console:

console:

```
object{"current_user":{"uid":"4","name":"cravushedal"},"csrf_token":"lY4vX3Ns_PrBkpPqoit4PEuEhXlimhKJ-xBt6ouUMXc","logout_token":"KOvJljv47rO3tRV3OG37ZKH57VWAG2gGxPe8nwCmN7A"}

login.service.ts:39 CSRF TOKEN"lY4vX3Ns_PrBkpPqoit4PEuEhXlimhKJ-xBt6ouUMXc"
```

> It says: ERROR in src/app/login.service.ts(37,65): error TS2339:
>   Property 'csrf_token' does not exist on type 'Object'.
>   [image]

Comment: Which line does the error refer to? Also why use `map` if you just return the same value? You can just use `localStorage.setItem` within `tap`.

Comment: this line: `console.log ('CSRF TOKEN' + JSON.stringify(user.csrf_token));` @Jeto

Comment: @Jeto yes, let me add an image to the console. ..

Comment: if I try to change map for tap, it gets `Property 'tap' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'`

Comment: Try to change `this.http.post(...)` to `this.http.post<User>(...)` and/or `map(user => ...)` to `map((user: User) => ...)`.

Comment: perfect, `map((user: User) => ...)` it works... but why? what is happening?

Comment: @ValRob because webpack and typescript checks the property at compile time and the property does not exists on `Object` if you are not specifically mentioning `User` as the type

Comment: When you call `post` without the type argument, the default return value is an instance of `Object`, which doesn't have any of the properties you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is due to Typescript not being able to compute the type of your `user` property.

When you call [`HttpClient#post` without a type argument](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L1742), it returns an `Observable<Object>` instance, and `Object` doesn't have any property (and, unlike `any`, isn't "flexible").

You need to type your call to `HttpClient#post` like this, so that the return value becomes `Observable<User>`:

```
this.http.post<User>(url, user, httpHaljson);
```

You could also specify its actual type when using `map`:

```
.map((user: User) => ...
```

Comment: Or just ```this.http.post<any>...```

Comment: @PMateus Sure works, but it's a bit of a shame not to use the actual type when we have it available :)