# Property 'csrf_token' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rtk-query

I am having this problem property 'csrf_token' does not exist on type '{}' from react redux query and I do not know how to solve it. The error is found on api.dispatch(setToken(refreshResult.data.csrf_token));

apiSlice.ts

```
import { setLoggedout,setToken } from '@/features/auth';
import { BaseQueryFn, FetchArgs, FetchBaseQueryError, createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import type { RootState } from '@/store'

const baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_BACKEND_URL


const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: baseURL,
    credentials: "include",
    prepareHeaders: (headers, {getState}) =>{
        const token = (getState() as RootState).userAuth.token
        if(token){
            headers.set('X-XSRF-TOKEN',token);
        }
        return headers;
    }
})

// Renew accesstoken here. Check response etc.
// Initial query => /refresh for new token => Do initial query again
const baseQueryWithReauth: BaseQueryFn<
    string | FetchArgs,
    unknown,
    FetchBaseQueryError
    > 
    = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
    // console.log(api);
    if (result?.error?.status === 403) {
        //Access token expire
        //Fetch /refresh to get a new access token
        console.log("Sending refreshtoken");
        const refreshResult = await baseQuery({url:'/user/refreshToken', method:"POST"}, api, extraOptions);
        // Get new access token
        // console.log(refreshResult);
        if (refreshResult?.data) {
            //call the dispatch action setToken
            //retry the initial query
            api.dispatch(setToken(refreshResult.data.csrf_token)); // Error found here
            result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
        }
        else {
            //Refresh token expired, logout
            api.dispatch(setLoggedout());
        }
    }
    return result;
}

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    tagTypes: ['Auth', 'User'],
    endpoints: () => ({}),
});
```

I tried creating a type but I do not know where to put it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49578995/property-csrf-token-does-not-exist-on-type-object

Answer (score 0):

If the [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery) are to be believed, `data` is simply declared as `any`, so you'll have to assert the type before accessing it like

```
if (refreshResult?.data) {
  const { csrf_token } = refreshResult.data as YourDataType;
  api.dispatch(setToken(csrf_token));
  result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions);
}
```